# Position an element using css

Tags: html, css

so while I was making a webpage for desktop only I ran into some trouble while trying to position some elements for example here is how I see it on my screen:

[image]

while on another screen here is what I see:

[image]

here is the HTML/CSS used for this :

```css
#Download
{
  position: relative;
  bottom:14rem;
  left: 43vw;
  background-image: url"(../image/download.png");
}
```

```html
<div id="Download">
  <h1></h1>
  <img src="image/download.png">
</div>
```

I tried multiple measuring units. thanks in advance.

Comment: You should give a try with this structure: `<div id="Download">
  <h1><img src="image/download.png" alt="Télécharger"></h1>  
</div>` and reset margins of h1. then `img {display:block;margin:auto;}`. There should be less difference to mind about. left will not be needed, and you should also use same font-size for h1 and bottom. Mind the alt attribute for img when it is supposed to be a text ...

Comment: Please use position : relative to the parent div and position : absolute to inner div and use left, right,top, bottom in inner div . this may help yours

Answer (score 1):

```
div{position : relative }

#Download
{
  position : absolute
  bottom:14rem;
  left: 43vw;
  background-image: url"(../image/download.png");
}
<div id="Download">
  <h1></h1>
  <img src="image/download.png">
</div>
```

Try this