# How to position elements in a webpage CSS

Tags: html, css

How would I be able to position all these elements in the middle of the webpage?

for example the `h1` a bit above the input, but all relative to each other, also taking into account that it should be responsive. I know how to position them using `position: absolute;` but I'd like to know what a better practice would be.

https://jsfiddle.net/w75ksg69/3/

```css
html {
     background-color: rgb(171, 248, 235);
        font-family: sans-serif,Tahoma, Verdana, 'Times New Roman';
    }

    h1#maintitle {
        margin: 0 0 0 0;
        text-align: center;
    }

    div#info {
        font-size: 1em;
        margin: 0.5em;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <h1 id="maintitle">Find your new abcde</h1>
    <div id="info">
        <input name="arrive" type="date" placeholder="Arrival date:">
        <input name="departure" type="date" placeholder="Departure      date:">
        <input name="guests" type="number" placeholder="Guests:">
        <button id="search_button" type="button">Search</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Position an element using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52140100/position-an-element-using-css)

Comment: http://learnlayout.com/

Comment: If you are saying middle of page that means vertical center. here is the solution, you can use flex box for your purposes.. https://jsfiddle.net/ssorabh/6ngkxc4L/8/

Answer (score -1):

I made all your inputs on the center using just text-align: center:

```
div#info {
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Hope, it helps